# Is there a way to tell whether a function has a matching clause without calling it in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

E.g. suppose I have a module named caller, and one of the functions defined therein contains this expression:

```
Callee:some_function(foo, Bar)
```

caller could try to catch function_clause, but how would caller know that it comes directly from Callee:some_function as opposed to some other function call (e.g. a call that Callee:some_function itself makes)?

Comment: I think you ought to be able to (1) find the module source file (2) parse the file (3) eval the function heads to see if they match. That's a lot of work, though.

Answer (score 4):

You could catch `function_clause` errors with try-catch, and check if the stacktrace matches:

```
-module(foo).

-compile(export_all).

maybe_apply(Mod, Fun, Args) ->
    try apply(Mod, Fun, Args)
    catch
        error:function_clause ->
            case erlang:get_stacktrace() of
                [{Mod, Fun, Args} | _] ->
                    {error, function_clause};
                [{Mod, Fun, Args, _LineNumber} | _] ->
                    {error, function_clause};
                Stacktrace ->
                    {error, other_function_clause, Stacktrace}
            end
    end.
```

Here is an example that shows how it distinguishes between a function clause error in `lists:filter` itself, and a function clause in a function called by `lists:filter`:

```
> foo:maybe_apply(lists, filter, [x, [1,2,3]]).
{error,function_clause}
> foo:maybe_apply(lists, filter, [fun(x) -> true end, [1,2,3]]).
{error,other_function_clause,
       [{erl_eval,'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-',[1],[]},
        {erl_eval,expr,3,[]}]}
```

Comment: You can make your life a bit easier by capturing the value of `catch Callee:some_function(...)`. In the event of a runtime error, you will get a stack trace as the third element of the tuple. See the [manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81078).

Comment: Ah, I thought get_stacktrace might be the key. For some reason, it wasn't doing what I thought it would when I first tried it. Thanks!

Comment: I guess this solution DOES call callee to probe whether it has matching clause. Still, it does distinguish between match failure and other failures, which in many cases is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use catch `(callee:some_function(foo, Bar))` and analyse the error message if any:

```
1> catch (lists:filter(5,[1,2,3])).
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{lists,filter,
                                 [5,[1,2,3]],
                                 [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1283}]},
                          {erl_eval,do_apply,6,
                                    [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,661}]},
                          {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,434}]},
                          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,684}]},
                          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,639}]},
                          {shell,eval_loop,3,
                                 [{file,"shell.erl"},{line,624}]}]}}
2> catch(lists:map(fun ({X,Y}) -> X + Y end, [{1,2},{3,4}])).
[3,7]
3> catch(lists:map(fun ({X,Y}) -> X + Y end, [{1,2},{3,4,5}])).
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{erl_eval,'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-',
                                    [{3,4,5}],
                                    []},
                          {erl_eval,expr,3,[]}]}}
4> 
4> catch(lists:map(fun ({X,Y}) -> X / Y end, [{1,2},{3,0}])).
{'EXIT',{badarith,[{erlang,'/',[3,0],[]},
                   {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},
                   {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1237}]},
                   {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,661}]},
                   {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,434}]},
                   {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,684}]},
                   {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,639}]},
                   {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,624}]}]}}
5>
```

you can recognize the case that you are looking for because it has the form:

```
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{callee,some_function,
                                     [foo, Bar],
                                     [{file,"callee.erl"},{line,LineNumber}]}|Stack]}}
```

Comment: nit: callee can fool you by returning a value of the same form though. Seems better to use try + catch, as suggested in other answer. But still, thank you!